# В Python не биндится кнопка A на движение плиты

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Код:

```
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
c = Canvas(window, width=960, height=720)
c.pack()
plita = c.create_rectangle(400,690,545,715,fill='grey')
c.bind_all('KeyPress-a', c.move(plita, 0, -1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался, функцию надо писать без скобочек

Comment: Какую функцию? Более подробнее опишите раз решили проблему